# python subprocess module can't execute shell

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

```
[root@localhost root]$ cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
system("/bin/sh");
}

[root@localhost root]$ cat auto 
#!/usr/bin/env python
subprocess.Popen(['/root/test'])
```

i want to use subprocess for executing new shell command line

but it's immediately closed i don't know why..

what should i do for continuing new shell command line?

if there are another way to do same thing instead of subprocess module, please let me know :)

sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 1):

`subprocess` needs to be imported:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(['/root/test'])
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're running your Python script by double-clicking it in some GUI instead of from the command line (because opening `/bin/sh` from a shell is pretty useless). That's causing you not to see the `NameError` saying `subprocess` isn't defined because you forgot to import it.

Fixing that is not going to solve your problem, though.

First, realise that your C program is superfluous; you can just start `/bin/sh` through `subprocess.Popen` directly. But if you're doing that by, as I'm guessing, running your script from a GUI, you aren't going to end up with a new terminal window with a shell running in it; `/bin/sh` is going to realise it's not running on a TTY and exit immediately.

Instead what you probably want to do is start a new *terminal*, and let that run your shell. How you do that depends on what terminal you normally use, but here's a possible way of doing it if you're using xterm (other common terminals include gnome-terminal or konsole):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os

os.execv('/usr/bin/xterm', ['xterm'])
```

(You'll want to use [`os.execv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.execv) rather than something from `subprocess` or `os.system`, because that makes the new terminal *replace* the Python process instead of running pointlessly as a child of it.)